# detecting touch on child sprite

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I added sprite B to sprite A as a child..

[spriteA addChild:spriteB];

my game logic is based on if spriteB was touched or not.
However I was not able to get spriteB to detect the touch.

I have converted the touchLocation to nodeSpace..
And I can get spriteA to detect the touch with no problem..

The if-condition I use is

```
if (CGRectContainsPoint(spriteB.boundingBox, touchLocation))
```

It'll be sweet if someone can point me to a direction..

spriteA is added to spriteBatchNode if that matters.

Thanks in advance!

Update:

I figure that the child is actually detecting the touch.
the reason it wasn't working was because I have the dirty tag set.

In short here's how my game works.
Targets popping from some hides.. and player touches on targets to get points.

I have a few arrays to hold targets at different location.
And I set dirty tag for each target..
target.dirty = TRUE when it pops
target.dirty = FALSE when it hides

this is equivalent to 
  If it pops, then it's clickable.
  If it's behind the hide, then it's NOT clickable.

so right before I enter my if-condition

```
if (CGRectContainsPoint(curTarget.boundingBox, touchLocation))
```

I have this

```
if(curTarget.dirty == FALSE) continue;
```

My problem is that when I have the above condition check.. I detect no touch..
But If I take the above condition away, I can detect all touches..
but the problem would become the reverse.. which is I am able to click on my targets even it's not visible..

the above logic works if I add the target sprites as a child of the layer instead...

Help!

Comment: Use Kobold2D (www.kobold2d.com). Then use [self containsTouch:touch] where touch is a UITouch object.

Comment: Thanks! but I have never dealt with Kobold2D before.. shouldn't cocos2d be able to handle this w/o kobold2d?